# How to check does interface with generic fit to class

Tags: java, generics

I have some interface with generic type `interface DummyInterface<T>` and i have class to which i have to set interface

```
 class DummyClass<T>{
        public void setDummyInterface(DummyInterface<T> dummyInterface){
            //set interface
        }
    }
```

Imagine the situation where i store `DummyClass` with different generics in `ArrayList`. When i get class from list i don't know the generic of class, and i want to check if interface has the same generic or not;
For example i want to check like this

```
if(dummyInterface<SomeTypeIKnow>.getGenericType() == dummyClass.getGenericType()){
      dummyClass.setDummyInterface(dummyInterface);
}
```

Comment: From what it sounds like you're doing, that's going to be impossible; you can't reconstruct the generic parameters associated with an arbitrary object.

Comment: You cannot pass in a `DummyInterface<T>` into `setDummyInterface` if `T` does not equal DummyClass's `T`.  You will get a compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) (a library that I authored) to resolve type arguments so long as the argument is captured in a type definition. For example:

```
interface DummyStringInterface extends DummyInterface<String> {}

Class<?> t = TypeResolver.resolveRawArgument(DummyInterface.class, DummyStringInterface.class);
assert t == String.class;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand your question, but this code will allow you to get the Generic types for an object. They allow you to perform reflection on the generic parameters of an object.

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class GenericClassUtils {

    public static <T> Class<T> getClassFromGeneric(
            Object parentObj,
            int oridnalParamterizedTypeIndex) throws Exception{
          Type[] typeArray = getParameterizedTypeListAsArray(parentObj);
          return (Class<T>)typeArray[oridnalParamterizedTypeIndex];
    }

    public static <T> Type[] getParameterizedTypeListAsArray(Object parentObj){
        return  ((ParameterizedType) parentObj.getClass()
                    .getGenericSuperclass())
                    .getActualTypeArguments();
    }
}
```

Perhaps by calling something like this:

```
Class clazz = getClassFromGeneric(dummyClass, 0);
if (clazz.isInstance(SomeTypeIKnow.class)){
     dummyClass.setDummyInterface(dummyInterface);
}
```